# Not able to refresh/reload Angular view via ChangeDetection.onPush strategy

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I am trying to update the view of an Angular Component when data changes. I was going through the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and thought this might solve my problem. However, I didn't succeed.

I have a upcoming-studies component and this is a child component of studies component.

> upcoming-studies.component.html

```
<div>
  <ngx-datatable
    #upcoming
    class="material"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="columns"
    [columnMode]="'flex'"
    [selected]="selected"
    [selectCheck]="selectUnselect"
    [selectionType]="'single'"
    [limit]="10"
    (select)='onSelect($event)'>
  </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

The `[rows]="rows"`, here variable rows gets data from backend using `HTTP` call.
I am trying to update the view, whenever this variable `rows` gets updated or whenever `HTTP` call is made. Here is part of my ts file.

> upcoming-studies.component.ts

```
        @Component({
        selector: 'rmis-upcomingstudies',
        templateUrl: './upcoming-studies.component.html',
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
        styleUrls: ['./upcoming-studies.component.css']
    })
    export class UpcomingStudiesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

        // ToDo: Check specific data types
        @Input() rows = [];
        @Input() temp = [];
     constructor(private studiesService: StudiesService,
                    private exceptionService: ExceptionService,
                    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
            // Set up the column labels and properties for the upcoming study table
            this.columns = [
                {prop: 'protocol_number', name: 'Protocol Number', flexGrow: 1},
                {prop: 'start_date', name: 'Start Date', flexGrow: 1},
                {prop: 'end_date', name: 'End Date', flexGrow: 1},
                {prop: 'patient_count', name: 'Patient Count', flexGrow: 1},
                {prop: 'trial_country', name: 'Country', flexGrow: 1},
            ];
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.getUpcomingStudies();
        }
        ngOnChanges() {
        //Trying to print the `rows` and `temp` to see if changes in these variable are detected. so that I can run cd.detectChangese() method to update the view.
}
```

First time the `HTTP` call happens onInIt(), the next time I am calling `getUpcomingStudies()` of `upcoming-studies-component.ts` from a differnet Component (Neither Parent not Child) and that is when I need to update the view. The `HTTP` call is made and updated data is also returned that updates `temp` and `rows` variable but the number of rows on UI does not change. Basically, it reduces the number of rows from upcoming studies view, so I need to update that view so it shows 1 less row. As you can see, I have tried using `ChangeDetectionStrategy`, but I am not sure on how to make this thing work. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Update 1**: I think, my @Input() variables are not getting updated and thus no change detection, as I tried printing them in ngOnChanges, but ngOnChanges never got executed. Is there any other way to perform the same action?

**Update 2:**
I have made some changes in the ways `rows` and `temp` are updated. As I had mentioned earlier, upcoming-studies component is a child of studies component. I am passing rows and temp from studies to upcoming-studies component as shown below:

> studies.component.html

```
  <upcoming-studies [rows] = rows [temp] = temp>
    </upcoming-studies>
```

The studies component makes an HTTP call to get the data(rows and temp).

> studies.component.ts

```
public rows = [];
public temp = [];
ngOnInit() {
    this.getUpcomingStudies();
}
    getUpcomingStudies() {
    this.studiesService
        .getUpComingStudies()
        .subscribe(
            // the first argument is a function which runs on success
            (data) => {
                console.log('Data from backend-upcoming', data);
                this.temp = data['records'];
                // this.temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.temp));
                this.rows = this.studiesService.util_to_cal_time(data['records']);
                // this.rows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rows));
                // this.rows = data.records;

            },
            // the second argument is a function which runs on error
            (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.exceptionService.errorResponse(err);
            },
            // the third argument is a function which runs on completion
            () => {
            }
        );
}
```

For first time, ngOnInit in studies component, calls the `getUpcomingStudies` method. After this, it's called from another component. Let me know If you need more details.

> util_to_cal_time - It just modify the time and return the same array.

```
util_to_cal_time(studies: Array<any>) {
        for (const each of studies) {
            const sDate = new Date(each.start_date * 1000);
            each.start_date = sDate.getUTCMonth() + 1 + '/' + sDate.getUTCDate() + '/' + sDate.getFullYear();
            const eDate = new Date(each.end_date * 1000);
            each.end_date = eDate.getUTCMonth() + 1 + '/' + eDate.getUTCDate() + '/' + eDate.getFullYear();
        }
        console.log(studies);
        return studies;
    }
```

Comment: Angular does not perform a deep diff of Objects and Arrays when redrawing the screen. That means that if an object in your array is modified -- Angular will be none the wiser. You could try assigning your `rows` property a completely new reference (clone the array) each time it is updated. For example `this.rows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rows))` or if your using Lodash: `this.rows = _.cloneDeep(this.rows)`. If that works -- that will at least confirm your issue.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: No..not yet @Maximus... I am seeing that `ngOnChanges` detects change in `rows` and `temp` variables only first time.. Then any other change in these arrays is not being detected as pointed out by @Graztok. And hence I am not able to run ChangeDetection. Do you have any input on this?

Comment: how do you update `rows`, show some code

Comment: @Maximus - I have added Update 2, that should make things more clear. Let me know If you need any other info.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is with change detection. This `this.studiesService.util_to_cal_time(data['records']);` should probably return new reference to `this.rows` and the old one will be different and change detection should pick up the change. Can you maybe create a plunker?

Comment: I have added `util_to_cal_time` code. But what with `this.temp = data['records'];` , this should have got detected? I was reading that changes in `Array` are not detected by Angular. That might be the case?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to trigger the change detection in the array itself. So, once you are done populating the "rows" and "columns" component variables, just add the following two lines of code.

```
this.rows = [...this.rows];
this.columns = [...this.columns];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. There was no issue with ChangeDetection (It was even not required in my case). In my post above where I say `After this, it's called from another component. Let me know If you need more details.` , the problem was in the way I was making the call to the component method. I was using the `new` keyword to create the object of that component in order to call the `getUpomingStudies` method that and was giving me a fresh instance of the component each time. No wonder, my old component was never seeing the changes. It was a really silly mistake but that made me read and learn a lot about `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. Thanks everyone for their inputs!